# How to solve vmouseup being interrupted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mouseevent

I'm using jQuery Mobile to develop one single page to use in Android Webview.

There is an button which I need put some pressed effect, and then I use `vmousedown` to add press style class and `vmouseup` to remove the class added before. However, there are something interrupt the `vmouseup` process.

Reproduce:
First, press one button, and it trigger the `vmousedown` event.
Then, keep hold your finger and move outside the trigger area.
Finally, loosen your finger and you will see it keeps the state that you hold it.

I have done a demo to test, and find that it even won't trigger `vmouseout` or `vmousecancel`, the last event have been triggered is `vmousedown`.

Is there anyone know why this happen and how to solve this?
This is code : [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/icese7en/wxsLufk3/)

Answer (score 0):

When I written an example to test gesture event, I noticed that, the `taphold` event will be triggered and then I put it in on method and this problem fixed.